# How to configure Visual Studio Code to format according to my development standards?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I have tried using prettier but after a while came to the conclusion that it was not what I needed.

Then I found and installed "Beautify" and although it does what it should, I can not find clear information about how to configure it specifically as I need.

I have never dealt with formaters or even linters before, so I would really appreciate if someone could guide me on that.

How do I specifically configure what things I need to be formatted and block certain that occur by default?

What file do I need to modify?

- Very grateful for the help :)

Comment: Use `.editorconfig`